# How can I access the browser history on another computer?

Tags: history, chromebook

I was on a loaner Chromebook while my original one was being fixed. I need to know if I can access the browser history of the loaner now that I am back on my own Chromebook?

Comment: history of what application? Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Yes as long as you were signed in with the same Google account.

Press Control + H for History then on 'Tabs from Other Devices' at the top left.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Yes, if you were logged in on the same account and did not have the synchronization disabled.